ros2 humble to kill the "zombie" node
I use ros2 humble to integrate gazebo harmonic and have some problem with ros_gz_bridge.
My question is I have a node call the /ros_gz_bridge and it can't be kill.
I already reinstall ros2,gazebo or ros_gz_bridge but it doesn't work.
I try to killall but can't find the progress with parameter_bridge.
p.s use ps -ef |grep parameter_bridge.
And also use ros2 lifecycle set /ros_gz_bridge shutdown,and return me node not found.
Finally I reboot computer but not work.
it still in ros2 node list and publish data to topic.
help me to remove it from ros2.

The picture with node it doesn't be activated but always stay here


Please paste any code or console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, amongst other things...

Try
ros2 daemon stop

Then to restart...
ros2 daemon start

I find myself using these commands all the time in a variety of situations.

If it persists across reboots, maybe it is running on another remote machine ?
Else, I use this pitiless command to kill all zombie nodes:
# List PIDs of all processes whith "ros-args" in their commands, assumed to be ROS processes
# and kill them
pgrep -f "ros-args" | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' | sh


I pretty sure there's not remote machine to my computer, only I use for my simulation. I can't find the process with it through this cmd, it just like "disappear".that's very strange.However, I can build ros_gz_bridge and it will be two node wirh exactly same name, I am confused about it.
